# gmaps4rails select scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I have gmaps4rails working to show all locations.  But, I would like to show a map with workorders using their locations.  Workorder belongs_to location.

In the workorders controller, this will display all of the locations:

```
   @json = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

But, this won't display workorder locations:

```
   @json = Workorder.location.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

This is the view code:

```
   <%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list"} }) %>
   <strong><ul id="markers_list">  </ul></strong>
```

Comment: Whats the relationship between workorder and location?

Comment: workorder belongs_to location

Comment: Ok, whats the meaning of `Workorder.location`? Looks like a scope but it's a relation. I haven't used ActiveRecord for years but still looks weird

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to` specifies a one-to-one association with another class (It returns only one entry).

`to_gmaps4rails` is a method from Enumerable (it expects to be called on an Array).

Also, you can't call the relation directly from the class (it's not a class method, it's an instance method):
    Workorder.location.all.to_gmaps4rails

should be:
    a_work_order = WOrkorder.first
    a_work_order.location

and to use it with `to_gmaps4rails`

```
[a_work_order.location].to_a.compact.to_gmaps4rails
```

It isn't pretty, but it covers both when `location` is `nil` and when it returns something.